# Where to place simple "Accept Conditions and Book" Script in CMS

Tags: javascript, php, email, joomla, xss

Trying to place a simple Script on my Server, but reading about it makes me kinda nervous. I am using Joomla 3.x and sending Mails over Mandrill.

I want the user to book an event just with a click on a button - sending the ID and Name to my send.php file which sends a Mail to my employee so she can book the event.

So I just get the

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Data and send it with my Mandrill Send / mail() to my destination Mail.

But where should I safely place that .php file? I am not echoing any information, just use it in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Ajax to do that? We have published an excellent post on how to use Joomla's com_ajax [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-use-joomlas-ajax-interface-component-com_ajax). Then you won't need to use an external script, you can just add your script in a Joomla module, where it'll be part of the Joomla environment.